# Play JodaTime and Form Validation

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a problem using JodaTime format and form validation

I have Image entity :

```
@Entity
public class Image extends Model {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public long id;

@Constraints.Required
public DateTime dateTime;
}
```

And i have a form with this datetime picker :
http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#using-locales

If i inspect the DOM for my datetime attribute i found value=03/12/2015 11:19 AM.
But the validation form display me : **error.invalid**.

How can i fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: ok, i use something like stackoverflow.com/questions/11295776/…. I add @JodaDateTime("format") public DateTime dateTime;  Thanks